# Side navigation media query with javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi is it possible to change the width of my side nav with javascript once the viewport is at 700px to 100% instead of 450px?

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "450px";
}


function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be javascript? You'd be best off with css media queries in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need javascript , you can use media queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {

      #mySidenav{
          width: 100%;
      }
   }
```